# Exponential derivative using L'Hopital

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

[image: exp]

Obviously $f(x) =  e^x$ but we have yet to learn about that officially in this class.

The hint that was given was:In the deﬁnition of the derivative, set $t = 1/x$ to convert to a limit as $t → ±∞$, and apply L’Hopital’s Rule.

So $f'(x) = \lim_{x→0} t\cdot(e^x-e^0)$?

I am not sure exactly where to go with this.

Also, how do you do $e^x$ and limits in Tex? I couldnt get it to work.

Comment: Satisfying $\exp(x), \exp(-x)=1/\exp(x)$ is senseless.

Comment: Put dollar signs around the Tex expressions.

Comment: @GitGud: it is obvious that the end of the first line is cut, and it says "$\exp'(x)=$".

Answer (score 1):

As the suggestion says,
$$
\lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{\exp({-1/h^2})}h=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\exp({-t^2})}{1/t}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{t}{\exp({t^2})}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac 1{2t\exp({t^2})}=0.
$$
where L'Hôpital is used in the second to last equality.

The limit from the left is done exactly the same, with $t\to-\infty$.

Comment: Why the last $1/e^t$? If you are applying Hospies rule, you get $\frac1{2\exp(t^2)}$.

Comment: Why does it shift from h going to 0 to h going to infinity?

Comment: @martycohen: you are right, thanks.

Comment: @user105631: there a change from $h$ to $t$.